# Two MAMP/Wordpress sites, one with "missing MySQL" error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, local, mamp

I'm trying to do some major dev on a two sites I built a couple years ago. They're both just plain old Wordpress installs with some customized themes. I pulled them both down off production today in an attempt to get them running locally to do this dev. First one goes fine. Second one keeps throwing the

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which
>   is required by WordPress.

error. They're both running on the same MAMP install on my system, just different directories. So I'm pretty confused as to why there's a difference. Typical "check phpinfo" on server responses to this issue don't really help as they're on the same server and have the same settings. Nothing SEEMS out of place within wp-config or phpMyAdmin. Feeling lost... plz help.

Comment: Have you tried clearing browser cache? Also try to swap the names of 2 directories.

Comment: Tried both of those, with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, I'm dumb. My MAMP was defaulting to php 7. Turned it back to 5.6 and now I'm in business.